# How to use delimeter ^|^ for loading data file into spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have data and need to use delimeter as ^|^ to load into df.the df has no header data.

Comment: Did you check the [**documentation**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader)? You can use the `delimiter` option.

Comment: Hello Luis, i know that we can use delimeter, but the question here can use the 3 char symbol as a delimeter? As my code throws error that i cant use more than a single char as delimeter.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to make that clear, and not you can't. The documentation explicitly states: _"sets a **single** character as a separator for each field and value"_.

Comment: Hi Luis, so dont we have options to use multi char delimeter?

Comment: Built-in in spark, I believe not but I am not an expert. Maybe you can do your own csv parser. I would suggest you close this question and opening a new one being clear that you have read the documentation and that it says is one char but you have three chars. Maybe some spark guru can help.

Answer (score 0):

Delimiter option does not supported multi-char values. Instead you can load the file and split it based on delimiter

Input File:

```
A^|^B^|^1
C^|^D^|^2
E^|^F^|^3
G^|^H^|^4
```

Code:

```
val file = spark.read.textFile("C:\\PATH\test.txt")
      .map(line => line.split("\\^\\|\\^"))

  def getColAtIndex(id:Int): Column = col(s"value")(id).as(s"column1_${id+1}")
  val columns: IndexedSeq[Column] = (0 to 2).map(getColAtIndex)

  file.select(columns: _*).show
```

OutPut:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|column1_1|column1_2|column1_3|
+---------+---------+---------+
|        A|        B|        1|
|        C|        D|        2|
|        E|        F|        3|
|        G|        H|        4|
+---------+---------+---------+
```